# Changing DEM resolution when creating a slope raster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, arcgis-10.5, slope, resolution

I want to create a slope map using a LiDAR DEM. I think that I should use the `slope` tool; but I need a slope map with a 2m resolution and I'm not sure how to do that.

How can I have a slope map with a 2m resolution using a DEM with 1m resolution. See DEM's characteristics in picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before creating your slope layer (Slope tool is the right choice) you can use the `Resample` tool to change the cellsize of your input raster, without changing the rasters extent.
It is however important that you change `Resampling Technique` to `Bilinear` or `Cubic` which is the right choice for continuus data.

[image]